# When does React.js rerenders a component after I update the Redux's store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

when I `dispatch` an action in Redux the store is updated sequentially, i.e. if I have the following thunk:

```
function action(data) {
   return function(dispatch) {
      dispatch(anotherAction(data));
      dispatch(anotherActionAfterTheAboveUpdatesTheStore(data));
   };
}
```

The store is updated sequentially, meaning that after `dispatch(anotherAction(data));` the store is already changed.

However, I know that internally when we dispatch an action, `react-redux` re-renders a connected component through its `setState` method, which is asynchronous. Therefore I have some difficulties in understanding when does React effectively re-render the component with the new data.

Does it somehow guarantees to call `render()` after each Redux's `dispatch`?

Thank you for the attention.

Comment: The component, if defined as a function, will be called one or more times per state update. It will happen no matter if the new state is same or different from original afaik. To see each call, you can put console.log statement before the component returns and see how many times it happens. With components defined as classes, it’s the same unless you control updates via shouldComponentUpdate.

Comment: The idea is that component must return per every state update. It’s then up to reconciler to decide if the DOM needs to be updated.

Comment: "Does it somehow guarantees to call render() after each Redux's dispatch?" You could simply test it by adding say `console.log` to `render` method. I'd say this is true now because react batches `setState` calls within event handlers. But no matter how this works now this is implementation detail that might change in future. I wouldn't recommend to anyhow rely on this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It actually doesn't have much to do with redux. Redux just updates the state and react-redux passes **parts of the state as props**. Now it's up to React to detect that some props have changed and to run it's lifecycle methods and re-render if necessary.

Comment: Therefore after multiple sequential `dispatch` calls it may happen that `render` is not even called between two sequential dispatches?

Comment: @tonix yes. as @Tomasz Mularczyk said: It is possible that the `render` method never will be called in your example. It will only be called when the components state/props will change.

Comment: I understand, this makes more sense now. Another thing which often comes to my mind is how does React know that it needs to re-render when we map Redux's store's props to React component's props and not to React component's state? I know that `render()` is called when there's a `setState` call with state changes, but in `react-redux` what changes are the components props mapped to the Redux store... Does `react-redux` issue a fancy `setState` under the hood even if what changes are the components props and not its state?

Comment: React-Redux's `connect` function subscribes to the Redux store, and re-runs your `mapState` function after every dispatch. If the values you return from `mapState` change, then yes, `connect` effectively calls `setState()` to trigger a re-render of the wrapper component, which passes the new values as props to your own component.